# Grunt - grunt-xml poke variable destination name

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am updating an xml file using grunt-xmlpoke. The path of xml file is provided as a param. The problem is the first `WebConfigPath` (key) in files section is treated as a string. It updates a local copy of my xml file and names it `WebConfigPath`. `WebConfigPath` should be treated as a varibale in  key as well as value.

```
var grunt = require('grunt');

var PACKAGE_DIR = grunt.option('package-dir');
var WebConfigPath = PACKAGE_DIR + '\\myproj\\web.config';

grunt.initConfig({
    xmlpoke: {
        UpdateWebConfig: {
            options: {
                replacements: [
                    {
                        xpath: '//add[@key="StarterApp.Settings.CMode"]/@value',
                        value: 'TRUE'
                        },
                    {
                        xpath: '//system.web/authorization/deny/@users',
                        value: '?'
                        }
                    ]
            },
            files: {
                WebConfigPath: WebConfigPath
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this may not help @adnan-kamili as this was raised 3 years ago, but may help someone else (I hit the same issue).

I surrounded the **files** setting brackets to try and force xmlpoke to treat it like an array in the hope it would treat them differently.  Seems to work! #result

```
    files: {
        [WebConfigPath]: [WebConfigPath]
    }
```